# What does **climbed back into grace** mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

His two attempts to break away from his own tradition were signal failures: "Turtle Doves alarmed by Sparrow-hawk" and "Wolves on the Roman Campagna" came back to his studio in the guise of abominable heresies, and Eshley **climbed back into grace** and the public gaze with "A Shaded Nook where Drowsy Milkers Dream."

quoted from [The Stalled Ox](http://www.eastoftheweb.com/short-stories/UBooks/Stal819.shtml)

What does **climbed back into grace** mean?

Comment: Perhaps you could look over some of the advice we give on our [Details, please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) meta post, and then come back here to edit your question, and tell us where you found this quote.

Comment: Ohhhh, the Saki story. That makes sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To be in good graces with someone means they have a good opinion of you; to be in their good favour ([Link](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+good+graces)).

The best way to explain 'climbing back into grace' in this context is that the subject of your quote, Eshley, possibily had a bad response to their previous works and this new one had a good response from the public and restored their opinion of him/her. They essentially climbed back into good graces.

Edit - There is also the more literal meaning along the same lines: to fall from grace is to get on the wrong side of the people (or god). So climbing back into grace has the same meaning as the above. ([Link](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fall+from+grace))

Comment: Eshley is an artist and two of his paintings weren't received well by the art critics, therefore he "fell from grace" within the public's eye and the art community. His next painting – _A Shaded Nook where Drowsy Milkers Dream_ – put him back into good graces because it was such a good painting. It's worth noting that Saki stories are often filled with humorous and over-the-top anecdotes, and this is one of those.